# Heroku :deply without using proxy in react

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

In my Mern stack project 
I am calling my all backend API like...

`` fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/brands/create/${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(name),
  }) ``

and in my.`.env` file
I have 
`API_URL:localhost:5000/api`

Now i want to deploy this app on heroku but on heroku fetch method will not be able to access `localhost:5000/api`
then what should i do?
I searched it on gooogle lot of people use proxy but is there any way i can do that without making proxy?
if 'No' then please tell me how to do it with proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your backend application on heroku alongside the frontend. You can change the deployed front end to point to:

backend_heroku_app/bands/create